# Inherited classes in a C++11 priority queue

Tags: c++, inheritance, priority-queue

I'm new to OOP in C++ and I'm not sure if this will work but I'd like to have multiple class types in a C++ std priority queue.

I set the classes up so that they all inherit from a base class and then use the base class to make all the functions, I just don't know how to make everything call the child class functions though. At the moment when I call the `foo()` function it calls the parent function rather than the child function

Is there a way to cast back without explicitly knowing what type it is? I'll have several different child classes which will do different things not just the single one shown.

The output of the code is currently `Parent` when I would have guessed it was `Child`.

I have a feeling I'm doing something wrong with the `virtual` keyword, should `foo()` be a purely virtual function?

**Parent.h**

```
#pragma once
class Parent{
    public:
        virtual ~Parent(){};
        virtual std::string foo() const { return "Parent"; }
};
```

**Child.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "Parent.h"
class Child: public Parent{
    public:
        Child();
        ~Child();
        std::string foo() const;
};
```

**Child.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Parent.h"
#include "Child.h"

Child::Child(){}
Child::~Child(){}
std::string Child::foo() const{ return "Child"; }
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include "Parent.h"
#include "Child.h"
using namespace std;

//Fake compare function for compilation, real one calls a compare method
class comparefunction{
    public:
        bool operator()( const Parent& p1, const Parent& p2) const{
            return true;
        }
};

int main(){
    priority_queue<Parent, vector<Parent>, comparefunction> pq;
    Child c;

    pq.push(c);

    cout << pq.top().foo() << endl;
    pq.pop();
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that you should ALWAYS declare the destructor of a base class as `virtual`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Polymorphism came into play when you try to use `Base` class `pointer or references` to call `derived class` functions (virtual).

In your case, you simply put object of `Child` class into a `priority_queue` that stores `Parent` objects. There is no `pointer` or `reference` to `Parent` class involved in this case. You will have `sliced` objects into the priority queue. Therefore, when you do:

```
cout << pq.top().foo() << endl;
```

It will output:

```
"Parent";
```

FYI: object slicing  means when you assign an object of a subclass to the super class. The superclass knows nothing of the additional information in the subclass, so the additional information of subclass gets "sliced off".

Comment: taocp has answered your problem quite clean. As an addition to his answer, this code will not compile at all basically. In your foo function implementation for child class case i see that the function does not return anything whereas it was supposed to return a string object.

Comment: @mecid thanks. yes. the child class foo function does not have return statement. I should have pointed that out.

Comment: Sorry about that, I fixed the code so it compiles now.

Is there a different way I can do this so that it does what I want?